# How do i install pygame on python 3.11.0 it's showing the following error

Tags: python, pygame, python-3.11

Whenever i try to install pygame, it says it has error: subprocess-exited-with-error
python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully. exit code 1

Comment: That's only telling that there was an error. The interesting stuff is further up.

Comment: python 3.11 is still new, you have to wait until all libraries support it, i am guessing pip will try to compile the libraries on your system , which might not be ideal, downgrading to 3.10 for a month or so will save you a lot of headache.

Answer (score 11):

`pip install pygame --pre` This should fix it for now. You can upgrade to the normal version once it launches